# Gas limit too low when using transaction data field

Tags: web3js, contract-invocation

I am using **web3.js** to send a transaction. This is the code that I have currently:

```js
async function sendTx(tran, ethAddress, privateKey, value=0) {
    var tr = {
        chainId: await web3.eth.getChainId(),
        gas: 300000,
        nonce: await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(ethAddress),
        value: web3.utils.toWei(value, 'ether'),
        data: tran.encodeABI()
    };

    try {
        tr.gas = await web3.eth.estimateGas({
            from: ethAddress
        });
    } catch {
        console.error('Could not estimate gas');
    }
    
    var signedTx = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(tr, privateKey);
}

var sc = new web3.eth.Contract('abi', 'contract address');
await sendTx(sc.methods.someMethod('param1'), 'ETH address', 'privateKey');
```

If I run it, I get the following error:

`Uncaught (in promise) Error: Signer Error: gas limit is too low. Need at least 53204`

If I remove `data: tran.encodeABI()`, everything works fine.